# Checking assumptions for linear regression with categorical variables

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, heteroscedasticity, assumptions, linear

I am doing a regression analysis on review star rating of VR headsets as a dependent variable and 14 attribute dummies. Each dummy is an attribute such as price, resolution, comfort with 3-1 levels (positive mentioned in review, negative mentioned in review, not mentioned). I am now checking assumptions for the linear regression. I have read on this forum that the linearity can't possibly be violated but I can't get it to work for the assumptions homoscedasticity and normally distrubuted errors. I have read some other posts about doing some test but I havent succeed in applying them correctly in SPSS myself. Can anyone help me in checking these assumptions for my research?

Thanks!

Comment: If star rating has only five values linear regression seems sub-optimal. I think you may need an ordered logit model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That type of regression goes beyond the scope of my assignment (forgot to mention that its for a class i'm taking). The lecturer told me that it was ok to use linear regression so sub-optimal is fine. But is it even possible to test these assumptions?